# Is it possible to extract Raid Controller configuration index from on to another?

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid5, raid10

We have a Fujitsu server with this specific RAID Controller (FUJITSU PRAID EP400i / EP420i).
We want to export the configuration of that RAID Controller to a new one, so in case that RAID controller stops working, we replace the new one with the exact configuration from the previous one. From what I know, I need to find a way to access the index file and copy to another raid controller, does anyone here knows if it is possible and how? Greetings.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, that the servers Works with EXSi

Comment: I don't know about this specific RAID controller, but on many others (Adaptec, for example), the disks store the RAID metadata so you can swap them from controller to controller (with the same firmware and controller model) at leisure. Of course the "root" controller settings like SGPIO etc. won't be transferred. Usually I just insert the controller into some board, set the same settings, remove it and store it away as replacement. Never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

All Disks which are connected to the RAID controller have their own metadata of current configuration and in case of failed RAID controller it is enough to just replace it. The new RC will ask you to import existing configuration. **Note:** You need same firmware level on each raid controller. Check this link - http://ask.microsemi.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16881/~/how-to-replace-a-sata-or-sas-raid-controller-without-loss-of-data%3F

```
*Scenario 1: Replacing a controller with the same model

When you power the computer back on after the controller has been replaced, the RAID controller will automatically detect the RAID table information stored on the drive and will store the information within the NVRAM of the Adaptec RAID controller. At this point, you have successfully replaced the controller.*
```